# Should I add control event handlers programmatically within Page_Init?

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I want to add event handlers programmatically to the server controls rather than using their predefined `OnClick` properties, etc. But which would be considered a better practice for defining handlers:

1. Define them in `Page_Init`
2. Define them in `Page_Load`

...and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Page_Init
```

Everything that has to be maintained between page cycles should be declared in `Page_Init`, not `Page_Load`.

**edit** All the initialization, like adding event handlers, and adding controls should be added during initialization, as the state is saved between page cycles. Handling with the content of controls and the viewstate, should be done in `Load`.

Check also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx.

> **Init**
>
> Raised after all controls have been initialized and any skin
>   settings have been applied. Use this
>   event to read or initialize control
>   properties.

.

> **Load**
>
> The Page calls the OnLoad event method
>   on the Page, then recursively does the
>   same for each child control, which
>   does the same for each of its child
>   controls until the page and all
>   controls are loaded.
>
> Use the OnLoad event method to set
>   properties in controls and establish
>   database connections.

Comment: for my edification, why is that?

Comment: Then in which conditions do I have to use `Page_Load` ?